# FTPS via proxy authentication

Tags: authentication, ssl, proxy, ftp, ftps

Is there a possibility to have an FTPS server connection via proxy with authentication?

To connect to normal FTP Server with proxy authentication, I used FTPHTTPClient from Apache Commons. But, I couldn't find a way to set proxy details within FTPSClient. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FTPHTTPClient docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPHTTPClient.html), it *looks* like you would use:

```
// If you are proxying via HTTP CONNECT, use port 80.
String proxyHost = "proxy.example.com";
int proxyPort = 80;
FTPHTTPClient client = new FTPHTTPClient(proxyHost, proxyPort);

String realHost = "ftp.example.com";
int realPort = 21;
client.connect(realHost, realPort);
```

Hope this helps!